# Why isn't my subclass method (symbol) found?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am very new to Java, and am working out a simple program showing inheritance. I am having issues accessing a method in a derived class, since it seems my variable definition does not use the subclass name, but the superclass name (Accounts). Why is it when I call the deposit method, a cannot find symbol error occurs?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;


public class Accounter {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static Accounts myAccount;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result; //holder for user input
    double amount; //holder for desposits and withdrawals

    System.out.println("What kind of account would you like to setup?");
    System.out.println("Checking[1] or Savings[2]");
    result = input.nextInt();

    if(result == 1) {
        myAccount = new Checking();
    } else {
        myAccount = new Savings();
    }

    myAccount.deposit(199.99);



}

}

class Accounts {
double balance;
public String accountName;
public Date dateOpened;
public Date today = new Date();

public Accounts() {
    dateOpened = today;
}
public Date getDateOpened() {
    return dateOpened;
}
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
}

class Checking extends Accounts {
public void deposit(double amount) {
    this.balance = this.balance + amount;
}
 }
 class Savings extends Accounts {
public void deposit(double amount) {
    this.balance = this.balance + amount;
}
 }
```

Comment: Does your `Account` class defined this method? No.

Comment: Does the super class have to define it? I thought since I was instancing a subclass, I have access to those instance methods and properties?

Comment: The super-class has to define the signature of the method to be inherited by sub-classes. Then if any sub-class contains the same signature, it is considered to be inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Declare `class Accounts` as `abstract`.
2. Declare `double balance` as a `protected` field in this class.
3. Declare `public void deposit(double amount)` as an `abstract` method in this class.

Comment: and also make the Accounts an abstract class (a non-abstract class cannot have abstract methods)

Comment: Thank you. So does all derived methods have to be defined in the superclass first?

Comment: Well, if you intend to use them with an object of the super-class, then yes. If you were calling this method using a pointer (pardon my C++) of type `Checking` or `Savings`, then you wouldn't get that compilation error. But because you're using a pointer of the super-class type, you must declare this method in that class.

Answer (score 1):

deposit is not defined in your base class, what you should do is,

define this method in base class and override it in your sub classes.

```
public class Accounts{
  public void deposit(double amount) {
  }
}

class Checking extends Accounts {

  @Override
  public void deposit(double amount) {
    this.balance = this.balance + amount;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is equally correct, but I felt the abstract declaration made more sense rather than an empty method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`myAccount` is an instance of `Accounts` which is your base class.

You cannot access methods from the derived classes directly from a reference to the base class.

To call that method, you'd need to cast to the desired derived class:

```
if(result == 1) {
    myAccount = new Checking();
} else {
    myAccount = new Savings();
}
if(myAccount instanceof Checking)
    (Checking)myAccount.deposit(199.99);
else if(myAccount instanceof Savings)
    (Savings)myAccount.deposit(199.99);
```

...**BUT**...

Since your derived classes share the same method, it would be best to define that method in your base `Accounts` class like so:

```
class Accounts {
    ...
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        this.balance = this.balance + amount;
    }
}
```

Then call your method as you did originally. This way you don't have to check whether `myAccount` is instance of one derived class or another. And if you need to change the behavior of that method in a future derived class, you can override it.